# скачивание файла с сервера node.js

Tags: node.js, http, get, express

Как это реализовать?

```js
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    let get = request.url;
    get = get.replace("/favicon.ico", "");
    get = get.replace("/?", "");
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync("ver.txt", "utf8");
    if (get < fileContent) {
        // Автоматически начинается скачивание файла "setup.exe" с сервера
    }
    response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        response.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=setup.exe"
        });
        fs.createReadStream('./setup.exe').pipe(response);
```

Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой модуль [node-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static).

В принципе, если его установить глобально, то не нужно писать никакого кода, просто перейти в нужную папку для расшаривания и запустить короткой командой `static`.

```
# Расшарить текущую папку
$ static
serving "." at http://127.0.0.1:8080
 
# Расшарить папку /srv/www/public
$ static /srv/www/public
serving "public" at http://127.0.0.1:8080
 
# Другие варианты запуска 
$ static -h
```

Либо короткий код поднимет веб-сервер с поддержкой заголовков кеширования в браузере (с отслеживанием факта изменений файлов на сервере), возможностью докачки файлов, а также ещё некоторыми плюшками.

```
var static = require('node-static');
var fileServer = new static.Server('/srv/www/public');

require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response, function (e, res) {
            if (e && (e.status === 404)) { // Если файл не найден
                fileServer.serveFile('/404.html', 404, {}, request, response);
            }
        });
    }).resume();
}).listen(8080);
```